# Mongodb cursor method sort

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

```
/**
 * @param $key
 * @param $value
 * @param $collection
 * @return array | \MongoDB\Driver\Cursor
 */
static function simpleSelect($key, $value, $collection)
{
    $con = \Core\Model\Mongo::getConnect();

    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(
        array(
            $key => $value
        )
    );

    return $con->executeQuery(\Core\Helper::getDb()['mongodb']['db'] . '.' . $collection, $query);
}
```

I develop class, for mongodb driver. And I have trouble, how to I can call function `sort` for mongoDB, for example https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/ in this documentation I read what `cursor` have `sort` but in php `\MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` class don't have `sort` method...

---

I fixed this by modified my code

```
/**
 * @param $key
 * @param $value
 * @param $collection
 * @return array | \MongoDB\Driver\Cursor
 */
static function simpleSelect($key, $value, $collection)
{
    $con = \Core\Model\Mongo::getConnect();

    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(
        array(
            $key => $value
        ),
        array('sort' => array('time' => -1))
    );

    return $con->executeQuery(\Core\Helper::getDb()['mongodb']['db'] . '.' . $collection, $query);
}
```

method query have 2 parameters, options this is array can contain sort, ordered and other options for collection. But this is not finish code because I want create new method for set sorting and other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP the syntax used to sort a Mongodb collection is

```
// Sort on field x, ascending 
$cursor->sort(array('x' => 1));
```

Your code can be modified to :-

```
static function simpleSelect($key, $value, $collection)
{
    $con = \Core\Model\Mongo::getConnect();

    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(
        array(
            $key => $value
        )
    );
    $cursor = $con->executeQuery(\Core\Helper::getDb()['mongodb']['db'] . '.' . $collection, $query);
   $cursor->sort(array('x' => 1));
   return $cursor;
}
```

Comment: Yes I returned this `$con->executeQuery` he return this class `\MongoDB\Driver\Cursor`, but `sort` function undefined.

Comment: I can't user `MongoClient` because my project in php7.* and I can't find mongoClient extensions

Comment: Try to execute the query again with key as fieldname on which the data has to be sorted and value as 1 and instead of $collection pass $cursor as parameter.

Comment: I edit my answer and write how to i fix my problem, you answer helped me googling and search answer in internet...